# How to use gtkmm with EGL

Tags: c++, gtk

I found [this](http://bobthegnome.blogspot.com/2014/09/using-egl-with-gtk.html) blog post that has an example on how to use EGL with GTK. However I use gtkmm on my project, therefore I need to find how to do things with it

I need to find these functions:

```
gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay
gtk_widget_get_display
gdk_x11_window_get_xid
gtk_widget_get_window
gtk_widget_get_allocated_width
gtk_widget_get_allocated_height
```

on gtkmm. Their gtkmm probably return class instances, so I need to figure out how to get the C object these classes point to as well

If we [look at the GTK functions](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-X-Window-System-Interaction.html), let's see an example:

```
Display*    gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay ()
```

It returns a `Display*`. Meanwhile, in the [gtkmm for Display](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Display.html) we see that `gobj()` returns the C object `GdkDisplay*`:

```
GdkDisplay*     gobj ()
```

which is not the same object.

So, how to find the gtkmm versions of these functions?

**UPDATE2:**

based on the suggestions in the comment, I made a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <epoxy/gl.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <EGL/eglext.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
class MyOpenGLArea : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    MyOpenGLArea()
    {
        set_title("Test");
        set_default_size(640, 360);

        add(vBox);

        glArea.set_hexpand(true);
        glArea.set_vexpand(true);
        glArea.set_auto_render(true);
        vBox.add(glArea);

        glArea.signal_realize().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyOpenGLArea::realize));
        glArea.signal_render().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyOpenGLArea::render), false);

        glArea.show();
        vBox.show();
    };

public:
    Gtk::GLArea glArea;
    Gtk::Box vBox{Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, false};

    void realize()
    {
        EGLBoolean eglStatus;
        EGLConfig eglConfig;
        EGLint n_config;
        EGLint context_attribs[] = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE};

        eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay((EGLNativeDisplayType)gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay(glArea.get_display()->gobj()));

        eglStatus = eglInitialize(eglDisplay, NULL, NULL);
        if (!eglStatus)
        {
            printf("Error at eglInitialize\n");
            switch (eglStatus)
            {
            case EGL_BAD_DISPLAY:
                printf("EGL_BAD_DISPLAY\n");
                break;
            case EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED:
                printf("EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED\n");
                break;
            case EGL_FALSE:
                printf("EGL_FALSE\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        eglStatus = eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, context_attribs, &eglConfig, 1, &numConfigs);
        if (!eglStatus)
        {
            printf("Error at eglChooseConfig\n");
            switch (eglStatus)
            {
            case EGL_BAD_DISPLAY:
                printf("EGL_BAD_DISPLAY\n");
                break;
            case EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE:
                printf("EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE\n");
                break;
            case EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED:
                printf("EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED\n");
                break;
            case EGL_BAD_PARAMETER:
                printf("EGL_BAD_PARAMETER\n");
                break;
            case EGL_FALSE:
                printf("EGL_FALSE\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    virtual bool render(const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::GLContext> &context)
    {
        glDraw();
        glFinish();
        return true;
    }

    void glDraw()
    {
    }

private:
    EGLDisplay eglDisplay;
    EGLSurface eglSurface;
    EGLContext eglContext;
    int numConfigs;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "");
    MyOpenGLArea myOpenGLArea;
    return app->run(myOpenGLArea);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Error at eglChooseConfig
EGL_FALSE
```

Something is still not rigth with the display I get

Comment: It is somewhat confusing, but there is the gtkmm `Gdk::Display` class, which is different from the `Display` type which comes from X11.  Calling `gobj()` on a `Gdk::Display` object should give you a `GdkDisplay` pointer, which you can pass to `gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay()` to get the (X11) `Display` pointer.

Comment: @whydoubt but to obtain a `Gdk::Display` from my program? GTK::Widget does not inherit from Display. Neither does GTK::Window.

Comment: `Gtk::Widget` and `Gtk::Window` both provide a `get_display()` method for the purpose of obtaining the `Gdk::Display`.

Comment: @whydoubt `eglGetDisplay ((EGLNativeDisplayType) gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay (gtk_widget_get_display (widget)));` this line requires the `GTKWidget* widget`. What if I do `gobj()` on my gtk widget and then static cast is to `GTKWidget*`?

Comment: `Gtk::Widget::gobj()` returns `GtkWidget*` as indicated in the [Gtk::Widget documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a6667a82920375b2ebde07bc1ffdc3641)

Comment: @whydoubt yes but I'm calling gobj() on an object that inherits from GTKWidget, which is an GLArea, so I need to static_cats, rigth? Do you think it works?

Comment: If you have a `GLArea*` object called `area`, you should be able to call `area->GTKWidget::gobj()`

Comment: @whydoubt things aren't working, please see my update. I tried your method but I couldn't do it because I couldn't find a a way to call `eglCreateWindowSurface` because I don't know how to get an window from a Display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find these functions:
>
> ```
> gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay
> gtk_widget_get_display
> gdk_x11_window_get_xid
> gtk_widget_get_window
> gtk_widget_get_allocated_width
> gtk_widget_get_allocated_height
> ```
>
> on gtkmm.

Some of these have easy-to-find wrappers in gtkmm. There is a naming system in place, after all. A GTK function named "`gtk_<thing>_<action>`" usually corresponds to the `<action>` method of the (capitalized) `<Thing>` class in the `Gtk` namespace – i.e. `Gtk::<Thing>::<action>`.

- [`Gtk::Widget::get_display`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a2f5880e2f1df5ff12295cf97c83de097)
- [`Gtk::Widget::get_window`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a403777253417c5c7653aac9e932de76b)
- [`Gtk::Widget::get_allocated_width`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#ad2c4a71d574be083a15e800d9dd02e2b)
- [`Gtk::Widget::get_allocated_height`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a29628aeb1606add96c4ef7aaa6f1cfe1)

That leaves the X11 interaction. I am not aware of a C++ wrapper for the "x11" portion of GDK, so you might need to [mix C and C++ APIs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-gobj-and-wrap.html.en). Just be aware of several similarly-named classes. For example, `Gtk::Window` and `Gdk::Window` are distinct classes. Also, `Display` (without a namespace) and `GdkDisplay` are distinct classes. (In particular, `Display` is not part of GTK nor of GDK; it is part of X11.)

Based on how the system is supposed to work (meaning that I have not tested this), the following lines should be a way to invoke GDK's X11 interaction functions from gtkmm. These assume a variable has been declared as `Gtk::GLArea glArea`, such as the data member from the example code.

```
gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay(glArea.get_display()->gobj());
gdk_x11_window_get_xid(glArea.get_window()->gobj());
```

The `get_display` method returns a smart pointer to a `Gdk::Display`. Calling the pointed-to object's [`gobj`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Display.html#aa5ba401c95c8f72ffbc974fa9ff7e2f1) method gives a `GdkDisplay*` which could then be fed to `gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay`. Similarly, `get_window` returns a smart pointer to a `Gdk::Window`, which can be converted to a pointer to the C object for `gdk_x11_window_get_xid`.

Comment: I did as you said. Please take a look at my update. I'm getting errors at eglChooseConfig. Something is not rigth with these displays.

Comment: @LucasZanella That's a new question.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.bassi.io/articles/2015/02/17/using-opengl-with-gtk/

> the OpenGL support inside GTK+ requires core GL profiles, and thus it won’t work with the fixed pipeline API that was common until OpenGL 3.2 and later versions. this means that you won’t be able to use API like glRotatef(), or glBegin()/glEnd() pairs, or any of that stuff.

So you need to switch to using the programmable pipeline (i.e. shaders, and all that entails) in order to get going with the Gtk::GLArea widget.

Comment: I updated the question to not use them. Could you take a look? I'm getting errors at eglChooseConfig